# User keep logged in android app using SharedPreferences not working

Tags: android, android-studio

We have seen in almost every app that the user logs in for the first time and the next time he opens the app, he goes straight inside the app without authentication. So I am trying to create exact same feature into my app, I followed documentation and coded into my app. Build is successful but it's not working, it keeps asking for authentication after closing app.

Code

```
package abc.xyz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    EditText username,password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("b", MODE_PRIVATE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                login();

                if(sp.getBoolean("Logged",false)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void login(){


        String user=username.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass=password.getText().toString().trim();
        if(user.equals("admin")&& pass.equals("admin"))
        {
            sp.edit().putBoolean("Logged", true).apply();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Success!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"username and password do not matched!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are saving the state as `true` then every time executing the login method instead you need to move to `MainActivity2` when the value is `true` so use

```
// move to next activity if user is authenticated
if(sp.getBoolean("Logged",false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                login();
            }
        });
```

Note : as mentioned by @shb , case sensitivity matter

Comment: Like this? `b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                login();
                sp.edit().putBoolean("Logged", true).apply();
                if(sp.getBoolean("Logged",false)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: no, you already have the logic to go to next activity in login method, just change you if statement as I shown though you can move `sp.edit().putBoolean("Logged", true).apply();` inside `if(user.equals("admin")` block, only want to set to true when we have the right values

Comment: I updated my question with latest code as per your suggestion, can you check? it's not working actually

Comment: `if(sp.getBoolean("Logged",false)){....)` should be outside click listener , as it was before otherwise , you need to click to execute the if block and it will also trigger the login logic which we don't want

Comment: After putting outside click listener when I open up app it's automatically going to secure area without asking username and password

Comment: isn't that you want `We have seen in almost every app that the user logs in for the first time and the next time he opens the app, he goes straight inside the app without authentication. So I am trying to create exact same feature into my app,`, uninstall you app and try again , it's the same you want

Comment: If you change any single line of code you have to build the apk again then you have to install it again into your phone. I did the same, so when I installed app again why it's directly going to secure area without asking username and password, this I what I said

Comment: no, click and hold your app icon and move it to uninstall  side, your preference has been stored so it is the expected flow now you have to uninstall app manually as mentioned and then run the project

Comment: I did the same brother

Answer (score 1):

You are saving

```
sp.edit().putBoolean("Logged", true).apply();
```

with an uppercase 'L' //Logged

but while retrieving you're using a lowercase 'l' //logged

```
if(sp.getBoolean("logged",false)){
//...
}
```

use either "logged" or "Logged" in both of the places.